# Does the FBI work with the RCMP to run criminal check on Canadians wishing to immigrate to the US

Tags: usa, greencard, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian applying for a green card.  Does USCIS/FBI get to use my biometrics to ask canada to run a criminal check on me?

Comment: The usual advice is that you should assume that they can and will do that.

Comment: As part of your green card application the US will ask you to provide police reports for every place you've lived since you turned 16. To get the RCMP report you'll need to provide finger prints and a copy of photo ID. The US doesn't need to ask the RCMP for this, you'll be asking on their behalf.

Comment: @Dennis that sounds like an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @Dennis I would like to add that they also take a picture of you when you go to get your criminal record check done.

Comment: @Dennis: Only if you're doing Consular Processing abroad. If you are doing Adjustment of Status in the US, it does not require you to provide any police reports, unless you've been arrested or charged with something.